# Comments can't contain that content?

Tags: discussion, comments, rules

So I added a comment to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467153/is-there-an-intelligent-way-to-know-the-name-of-the-library-to-link-to-at-compil#comment43490260_3467153):

> +1 - I guess people don't switch libraries frequently enough to have solved this basic problem, or to have an expectation of clearly documenting not just the header file needed, but the library name too. Meanwhile, people every day are wasting hours trying to figure out what to type after -l...

And was not allowed to submit it because, the automated blocking alert said, one shalt not explain reasons for voting. (I was able to bypass it by removing the +1 part.)

Ahem. What?

1) I wasn't explaining *why* I voted. I was adding the (IMO much-needed) sympathy/reminder that could lead people to remember to always document library link names and not just header files when they release libraries.

2) One of the most-frequent complaints I see about voting and comments is that people downvote but don't say why. In fact, I see people upvoting questions which have been downvoted without reason, just because there was no explaining comment.

3) Is this not excessive over-use of automated censorship? What this does to me, is add annoyance to my morning, and like other seemingly-overzealous heavy-handed content-controlling, discourages me from wanting to use the site overall, not just for this one minor comment.

Question: Isn't this a bit much? What about the direct conflict with the apparent desire of many to communicate what they particularly appreciate or want to correct about an answer? (i.e. often the positive +1 comments also point out the specifically good/unique parts of an answer, which is adding content.)

Comment: There has to be a better way to indicate that you're commenting in support of the answer, and not to criticize it or tell someone off. I know I've had more than a few cases myself of commenting to add to an answer which was then mistaken for criticism of the answer itself, resulting in displeasure on part of the poster.

Comment: "I upvoted your answer because..." That said, does this really need to be said?

Comment: Pardon the more-or-less duplicate question. It seems I was blinded by my annoyance from noting the duplication.