# Vague and unclear "Comment cannot contain that content" error

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

In advance, this is not a duplicate of [Comments can't contain that content?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280557/comments-cant-contain-that-content) or [Comments can't contain that content - "+1"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277804/comments-cant-contain-that-content-1-why-not), because neither concern the same content. This is both a request for clarification of a specific problem and a feature request for a site change. I'm also not expressing any opinion on the quality of the post in question itself, just the subject matter.

I attempted to direct someone to vendor-specific support for a [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28621428/62576) that is specific to their own situation, that is highly unlikely to benefit future readers here. I received the following error:

[image]

I'm somewhat confused. What specific part of that content isn't allowed? There seems to be nothing that violates any guidelines here; I'm attempting to direct this user to help for a situation that is too localized to be of general use.

(I had first used [this link](http://www.fast-report.com/en/forum/index.php?s=3905e8abadc55620a4956b390498f0a2&showforum=8), and thought it was the culprit, so I edited to use a [more generic version](http://www.fast-report.com/en/forum/index.php), but received the error shown.)

Rather than a broad *Comments cannot contain that content.*, this error should specify *what content* isn't allowed, particularly when it isn't something like *+1* or *Me too*. The error is similar to a compiler error that says *There's a problem with your code*, which of course is meaningless.

What should I change to allow me to guide this poster to a possible solution to this issue?

Comment: What a mess of a comment filter...

Comment: Maybe you need some exclamation mark to show the system that you're serious? Just a guess!!!!!

Comment: FastReport (or someone who hates them) was a huge spammer for the site hence the content that must be removed is the link to their site (which is blacklisted by domain). As a workaround I've used URL shortener once when I was posting a similar comment (but it's annoying). Either we could give them another chance, or e.g. allow to post links to their domain only to users with certain level of reputation. ([related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141743/179541))

Comment: If the rejection message was too specific about what's wrong, users would probably just do the simplest thing to bypass the rejection, i.e. add an asterisk in a suitable place or something.  So there is a reason the message is vague. But it's annoying when it happens and you have no idea how to fix a perfectly fine comment.

Comment: (Thinking out loud, maybe you can URL-encode the parts the filter dislikes?) `</smirk>`

Comment: When considering a work-around for this problem, I certainly wouldn't encourage people to fiddle/shorten the URL so that filter doesn't trigger. Instead, just omit the link and people will find it via Google easy enough.

Comment: @tripleee I've heard that justification for these vague error messages before, and it's total nonsense. If the user has any hope of _fixing_ their comment, they have to know what was wrong with it. So they have the option of using trial-and-error until they find out what part was not allowed, or just abandoning their comment altogether. Both of those options suck.

Comment: @JLRishe Agree for the case where no laziness or malicious intent is involved, but both of those exist.  Perhaps the anti-laziness, anti-maliciousness could be pinned to reputation, i.e. users with (say) 2k rep would not have the blacklist filter applied at all? (Oh, I see TLama already proposed that. Brilliant minds etc).

Comment: @JLRishe if the purpose of the comment filter was to fix the comment, that would be one thing.  If the purpose of the comment filter was to block certain content which historically has required moderator attention, and the moderators don't have the time/inclination to deal with, then preventing the comment entirely is a success of the filter *if* it was a successful hit in the first place.

Comment: The same goes for "this question does not meet our quality requirements" crap.

Comment: @Yakk Quite often the side effect of "successfully" preventing comments is that it creates frustration for users who are just trying to use the site without living under a nanny state. The site has [built-in safeguards against the word "accept"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252761/my-comment-was-removed-is-it-moderation-activity/252765#252765) because apparently that word hurts people's feelings, but it seems that blocking their comments and playing mind games with them with the _intent_ of getting them to abandon their comment is fair game.

Comment: @JLRishe I don't know if that is the intent or not.  I'm just noting that, from the moderators perspective, mass-filtering stuff that causes them to waste their time (and reduce their time waste) looks awesome.  Measuring if it causes users to leave the website, get angry on the website in other ways, or just makes their lives suck is difficult, but measuring "it seems to reduce my workload" is easy.  When you rely on measurement, you bias towards things that are easy to measure.

Comment: comment blocking (at least for suspected spammy content like that) should probably be disabled for users with sufficient reputation

Comment: @TLama: Thanks for that info. I'd missed the SE Meta post you linked. I think it's ludicrous that URL blocking like that is being done here for *comments*. I can see it for *answers* that are spamming content, but comments are meant to be transitory in nature. I've left a different comment for the poster of that question phrased differently (and linked here to the image so they can see the URL, at least). I'd still like an "official* (mod or SE employee) explanation of why this is necessary, particularly for users with some level of experience here.

Comment: @tripleee: *If the error was more specific, users might work around it* is a somewhat silly justification. As I said in my post, the error is like a compiler saying that your code is wrong without any indication of why or where. Sure, someone could work around it. Why frustrate a large number of people who are not trying to do anything but be helpful in order to deal with a very small percentage who are doing something wrong? I don't shoot my neighbor's dog because another dog of the same breed bit someone, and I wouldn't punish a child because of something another child did as prevention.

Comment: FWIW, they *do* have the ability to attach custom messages to these blacklist filters now. The older ones that existed before this feature naturally don't have them though. It should be a matter of getting the team to go back and write nice messages for each one.

Comment: @Yakk If the filter is meant to block users from commenting those comments altogether, then it should probably ban users from commenting *on that post* as soon as it's triggered once. Otherwise, some users will use trial-and-error to avoid the filter and post their comment anyway. (Now see why this might be a bad idea?)

Comment: If whatever FastReport did was naughty enough to get them on the blacklist, perhaps we ought to be rejecting *questions* with a message explaining what happened and that anything related to FastReport is unwelcome.  Letting OP know about the shady business practices of their software supplier would be doing them a favor.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I don't have any information (and I suspect neither do you) about *exactly* what was done or when, and I find it to be a bad idea to malign someone (especially in public) without having the details. FR is the default reporting software provided with Delphi and C++ Builder, meaning it's used by quite a few people. We don't ban questions here related to MS products despite *their* shady business practices several years ago, do we? Of course not.

Answer (score 87):

I can't help you with this particular case but, in general, I'd *really* like to see better error messages here.

> If the rejection message was too specific about what's wrong, users would probably just do the simplest thing to bypass the rejection, i.e. add an asterisk in a suitable place or something. So there is a reason the message is vague. ([src](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286525/vague-and-unclear-comment-cannot-contain-that-content-error?cb=1#comment157579_286525))

Optimising a GUI to defend against malicious use is not only arse-backwards design, but explicitly goes against SO's oft-touted policy of "assuming good intent". The correct way to deal with comments that were posted by brutishly circumventing a filter is to flag/delete them after-the-fact.

And then we can make the error messages *tell us what is wrong* so that we can post our content.

I consider this to be a bug in the same vein as the insanity-laden 15-second comment submission timer that we *still* have to deal with.

Comment: Moreover, dissuading people from posting helpful comments is just going to create unnecessary confusion and probably get the issue solved in a longer period of time.