# "Comments cannot contain that content"

Tags: discussion, comments

Similar to the [Vague and unclear “Comment cannot contain that content” error](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286525/vague-and-unclear-comment-cannot-contain-that-content-error), I recently received this error for a comment that said simply

> What have you tried?

However, this passed:

> What have you tried so far?

Umm... what?

What exactly causes this catch? I'm assuming inappropriate language, and similar content, but why would that get caught?

Comment: Unfortunately, the phrase "What have you tried?" is considered inappropriate language on SO. So it's banned. But as you can see, it's very easy to trick it.